# Import custom database into wp and keep the post id

Tags: posts, database, bulk-import

Hello guys I have a project where I need to import an old database to wp but I need a solution to keep the old id's as posts id so i can make the links look the same as the old website in this way we will avoid problems whit the links already indexed .

Any idea ?

Comment: What IDs are you referring to? Those of posts? Of users? Of other data? Do you need to merge entire databases or select table(s)?

Comment: the id of posts , I need it because the id is in the url .

Comment: I use a custom post url in the form of /%postname%+id-%post_id%.html

Comment: Are you importing from another WordPress site using the in-built importer, or have you written custom code to import data from a non-WordPress site?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to export your old site's posts from phpmyadmin, manually edit the .sql file that you download and then upload the new file to your site's database from phpmyadmin again!